# Can't set custom OpenAI model with langchain on nodejs

Tags: node.js, langchain

I am trying to set "gpt-3.5-turbo" model in my OpenAI instance using langchain in node.js, but below way sends my requests defaultly as text-davinci model.

```
const { OpenAI } = require("langchain/llms");
const { ConversationChain } = require("langchain/chains");
const { BufferMemory } = require("langchain/memory");

const model = new OpenAI({ model:"gpt-3.5-turbo", openAIApiKey: "###", temperature: 0.9 });
const memory = new BufferMemory();

const chain = new ConversationChain({llm:model, memory: memory});

async function x(){
const res = await chain.call({input:"Hello this is xyz!"});
const res2 = await chain.call({input:"Hello what was my name?"});
console.log(res);
console.log(res2);
}

x();
```

On documentation, i found the way to setting model with python. It sets with **model_name** attribute on the instance. But this way doesn't work with nodejs. Is there any way to setting custom models with langchain node.js ?

Comment: was this the issue?

Comment: Yes, solved with the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the [codebase](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchainjs/blob/main/langchain/src/llms/openai.ts#L117) and it seems like **`modelName`** is the parameter that you should use.

It's strange that the search function in the docs give no results for `modelName`. I guess it is the [same](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/reference/modules/llms.html#langchain.llms.AzureOpenAI.model_name) parameters used in python API but in camel case.

[Relationship with Python LangChain](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchainjs#relationship-with-python-langchain)

**edit**

Docs have it [here](https://js.langchain.com/docs/api/chat_models_openai/classes/ChatOpenAI#modelname)

Comment: I found it here https://js.langchain.com/docs/api/chat_models_openai/classes/ChatOpenAI#modelname

Comment: @MarvinQuiñónez maybe docs updated recently